# How to have an arbitrary value in an xpath command for web scraping with python scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I define an xpath command in python (scrapy) to accept any number at the place indicated in the code. I have already tried to put an `*` or `any()` at the position.

```
table = response.xpath('//*[@id="olnof_**here I want to accept any value**_altlinesodd"]/tr[1]/TD[1]/A[1]')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [regular expressions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions):

```
table = response.xpath('//*[re:test(@id, "^olnof_.+_altlinesodd$")]/tr[1]/TD[1]/A[1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Now assuming your any as like ANY, so you can try this.
`x_path = '//*[@id="olnof_{}_altlinesodd"]/tr[1]/TD[1]/A[1]'`
`x_path.format("put your any here, may b from rand function or extracting the value from somewhere else.")`
Then,
`table = response.xpath(x_path)` this will do the work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below workaround:

```
'//*[starts-with(@id, "olnof_") and contains(@id, "_altlinesodd")]/tr[1]/TD[1]/A[1]'
```

`ends-with(@id, "_altlinesodd")` suites better in this case, but Scrapy doesn't support `ends-with` syntax, so `contains` used instead